# Catch 22 with waiting for external application to finish processing and accidentally cancelling it before finishing

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, waitformultipleobjects

This is part of my code for launching an external application and waiting for it to finish:

```
DWORD WaitResult;
do
{
    WaitResult = MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1,
        // only 1 wait object
        &processInformation.hProcess, // worker thread
        FALSE,   // stop if any
        INFINITE,  // no timeout
        QS_ALLINPUT);
    if (WaitResult == WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1)
    {
        // Handle windows message
        MSG Msg;
        while (PeekMessage(&Msg, nullptr, 0, (UINT)-1, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TRACE3("%d %d %d\n", Msg.message, Msg.wParam, Msg.lParam);
            TranslateMessage(&Msg);
            DispatchMessage(&Msg);
        }
    }
} while (WaitResult != WAIT_OBJECT_0);
ASSERT(WaitResult == WAIT_OBJECT_0);
```

It is fine, until there is some issue with the calling exe that causes my app to indefinitely wait.

I did not put a figure for the time out because the exe being called is synchronizing calendar events with Outlook or Google. So depending on the users internet performance and the servers being synced with ...

Is there any way that I can safely add a time out that will not implement the actual process?

Comment: The code will wait indefinitely because of `INFINITE, // no timeout`. You could change that to specify an explicit timeout, instead.

Comment: @dxiv That is the catch 22. What if I choose a time out that is too small?

Comment: Define "too small". You can't both wait forever *and* timeout sometimes. If you trust Windows' [`IsHungAppWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-ishungappwindow) you could also check that before deciding you've waited long enough.

Comment: @dxiv Interesting method.I have no "definition" for "too small". I just don't know what value to use for explicit timeout.

Comment: You'll have to decide the "what" before worrying about the "how". You could wait for while, then if the time expired check IsHungAppWindow and if it returns negative wait some more. Or pop the question to the user, like Windows does sometimes when you logoff or shutdown and an app takes too long to comply.